# searchbox and submit button are appearing without borders

Tags: html, css

Very stupid question, but cant solve it...

In my php project the searchbox and submit button are looking weird, like the ones on .jpg picture below, why is that and how to fix this? (search = otsi:).

On a simple html form the very same lines of code are appearing normally, as the upper searchbox (with borders / otsi: )

[image]

Checked my css and it doesn´t seem to affect borders or boxes. Code on .php subpage is simple:

```
<header id="header">
<div id="logo"><img src="images/logobmw.png"></div>


<div id="searchbox">

<form action="search.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="search" name="value" size="25" >

<input type="submit" name="search" value="  otsi  " >

</form>
</div>
</header>
```

(Grey background on search-field is set by me in css, it was actually white, ergo, invisible because header´s background color is also white.

CSS *, body, wrapper and header are pretty simple as well:

```
 * {        
   margin: 0;
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

body {
  font-family: Calibri, Georgia, Verdana, arial;
  background-color: #F8F8F8 ;
  font-size: 105%;
  color: #303030;
  line-height: 1.4;
  margin: 0;
}

#wrp {
   width: 80%;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
}

#header {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The selector "*" applies to all elements (including INPUTs). This is removing the borders to your INPUTs.

Instead of using "*", most reset stylesheets will target individual elements like. If you replace that selector with what is below, this should fix your problem:

```
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks! If I want to change search-fields and submit-buttons border-style - how should I target them in css? I did as told, but they went 3D-style

Comment: With the current HTML you have, you could do:
INPUT[type="search"] {
    /*styles here*/
}
INPUT[type="submit"] {
    /*styles here*/
}